Does Cloud Run Actually Stream? It is complaining about Content Length
I am running on Cloud Run and have set up streaming from Flask to Browser. It appears to work well to transmit binary data (in this case it has been pickled and compressed).
def transmit_binary_data(N):                   # Yield compressed data in chunks 
   chunk_size = 16384                          # Maybe too small?
   print("Start transmitting compressed:", N, "chunk size:", chunk_size)
   for i in range(0, N, chunk_size): 
      yield e[i:i+chunk_size]

with app.app_context():
   response = make_response(Response(transmit_binary_data(content_length), 
                             mimetype="application/octet-stream"))
   response.headers['Content-Length'] = content_length
   return response

On the javascript side, I accumulate the chunks as they come in and then decompress and depickle. Perfect.
Except it doesn't work for very large (GByte) datasets. I get logging error:
textPayload: "Response size was too large. Please consider reducing response size."

What I think may be happening is that Cloud Run is creating an intermediate buffer in between the server and client, and that buffer is then too big.
Or maybe the mistake is my naivety in telling Cloud Run how much data is ultimately going to be sent::: response.headers['Content-Length'] = content_length ?
Suggestions appreciated.

Yeh, looks like setting response.headers['Content-Length'] = content_length  is exactly what is needed to disable streaming. Dumb of me...

Ok, yes, I messed up: if you set ['Content-Length'] as a header then Cloud Run assumes that you do not, in fact, want to stream data even if the mime type is set to stream. Oops.
But I want a download progress bar, which means the browser needs to know the length before starting the download. I created a new header variable [x-total-length] and set that to the total number of bytes.
response = make_response(Response(transmit_binary_data(content_length), mimetype="application/octet-stream"))
response.headers['x-total-length'] = content_length

# DONT DO THIS:: response.headers['Content-Length'] = content_length

Streaming started to work perfectly. Except the progress bar didnt work. Turns out to make [x-total-length]  visible to the browser I had to edit the _init_.py of the Flask
to make it a valid entry:
    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
#        Access-Control-Allow-Origin Stuff...:

        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-total-length') #for streaming data


Now it is all working.
